# two page ranges in one bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem getting to work a bibliographical entry, a chapter in an edited volume, for which I have to supply two page ranges, one for the chapter itself, a second for the notes. I get "pages" as output, but the page range does not appear. See example below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}


@incollection{Payne2006,
author = {Payne, Richard K},
year = {2006},
title = {Introduction},
booktitle = {Tantric Buddhism in East Asia},
editor = {Richard K. Payne},
location = {Somerville, MA},
publisher = {Wisdom Publications},
pages = {1–31 (notes on 227–234)},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output: [image: no page range]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pages` is a range field. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) of `biblatex` says:

> **Range fields** consist of one or more ranges where all dashes are normalized
>   and replaced by the command `\bibrangedash`. A range is something optionally followed by one or more dashes optionally
>   followed by some non-dash (e.g. 5–7). [...] With Biber, range fields
>   will be skipped and will generate a warning if they do not consist of
>   one or more ranges. [...]

The expression `1--31 (notes on 227--234)` does not contain a comma, thus it is one page range, but is has *two* dash sequences (I have used the ASCII letters here). This causes `biber` to complain a warning:

```
WARN - Range field 'pages' in entry 'Payne2006' is malformed, skipping
```

And the `pages` entry vanishes.

The second dash sequence can be hidden by using the command `\bibrangedash`, which would be placed instead of the dash sequence in a correct page range. Then `1` is the start page and the whole expression `31 (notes on 227\bibrangedash234)` the end page of the page range.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Payne2006,
  author = {Payne, Richard K},
  year = {2006},
  title = {Introduction},
  booktitle = {Tantric Buddhism in East Asia},
  editor = {Richard K. Payne},
  location = {Somerville, MA},
  publisher = {Wisdom Publications},
  pages = {1--31 (notes on 227\bibrangedash234)},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Your suggestion fixes it. Still why it happens is not fully clear to me. `biber` here (1.8) does not complain about it. And if I slightly change the `pages` field to include a comma, I'm getting a different behaviour: `pages = {1–31, notes on 227–234},` doesn't output `pages`, but gives me the first range twice. Also this gets fixed by replacing spaces with tildes though.

Comment: And another even more complicated example works just fine: `pages = {122--137, 189--191 (notes), 361--400 (bibliography for the whole book)},`

Comment: @muk.li In an earlier version of the answer, I had also replaced the spaces. But it was not necessary in this case. The duplication of the first page range looks like a bug.